# Angular : Routing to child component with navigate method with a relative route does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Example used is given in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/route-parameters-prav-zajegu?file=app/app.component.ts)

This is how routing is structured

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginViewComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'home', component: HomeViewComponent },
          { path: 'catalog/:id', component: CatalogViewComponent }
        ]
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
    ])
  ],
```

When I am in the login component, I can go to home component with this absolute route

```
this.navigate(['login/home']);
```

I can also use `navigateByUrl()` like this

```
this.navigateByUrl(['login/home']);
```

But I don't understand how to route relatively with `navigate()`

```
this.navigate(['home'], { relativeTo: this.route });
this.navigate(['/home'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

None of these methods are routing to homeComponent

Comment: Hi Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making child routes, I just have another route with the same name in the path:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: "activity", component: ActivityComponent },
{ path: "activity/orders", component: OrdersComponent },
```

If I am in the `activity` component, I navigate to orders by:

```
this.router.navigate(["orders"], { relativeTo: this.route });`
```

**import and constructor in the activity component**

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) {
```

Comment: I created this project to understand how relative routing works in Angular. Your answer is more like a workaround and does not explain why it doesn't work in my case.